# Mechanical Turk tutorials or how-to guides

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

does anybody know of any tutorials/resources that discuss integrating Amazon's [Mechanical Turk](https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome) and Rails? (besides those resources that Amazon already provides)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated RTurk and continued development, it should work for most jobs. Here's a little tutorial I wrote up on it - http://squarepush.com/ps/2009/08/11/mechanical-turk-in-ruby/

I'll be doing a more rails specific one in the next few days.

Comment: Alas, this link is now Broken :\

Comment: I'm using rturk with some degree of success.

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at my gem [Turkee](http://github.com/aantix/turkee).  Built on top of RTurk, should help streamline the creation of external forms and importing the worker entered data back into your models.

Comment: how do you manage the life-cycle of a HIT going though the turk system. I currently use turkee to post hits and that works fine, but I have no feedback on the HITs open in the system, which ones were rejected etc. Should I build this out w/ turkee or rturk?

Answer (score 1):

[RTurk](http://webchicanery.com/2009/06/20/4-minute-work-week/) is incomplete, but looks promising.